# Want inline list to disappear both right and left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm prototyping on a new project where I want a calendar to be shown like an inline list. 
No biggie so far, but the little tricky part is that I want it to show less dates when the window resizes and still have the current date centered in the window..

My code down here, just makes the right hand side disappear (see image) with the .content's overflow: hidden and ul's white-space: nowrap doing the magic. But still. Not what I'm looking for. The yellow current box should be centered... *draging my hair and execute a facepalm*

Javascript is nice but if you've got a solution in css, it's even nicer. :)

Here's an pen to it too.. [http://codepen.io/PatJarl/pen/eLJyr](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nEIsF)

```
.m-racecards {

    .content {

        padding: 5%; 
        max-width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;      
        overflow: hidden; 
        text-align: center; 

        ul {
            white-space: nowrap; 

            li {
                font-size: 25px; 
                display: inline-table;
                padding: 10px; 
            }
        }

        .current {
            background: $proto-yellow; 
        }
    } 
}
```

The html is quite straight forward...

```
<div class="m-racecards">
 <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>10</li>
      <li>11</li>
      <li>12</li>
      <li>13</li>
      <li>14</li>
      <li>15</li>
      <li>16</li>
      <li>17</li>
      <li class="current">18</li>
      <li>19</li>
      <li>and so on.... </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: This is wrong.. please help.]

Comment: Post your html css here or jsfiddle! so we can fix this issue without much effort

Comment: Now there are html added too.. right now just a div with an ul-list...

Comment: Now with a pen to. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it happen with a little jQuery like this :)

```js
$('.current').each(function() {
  var leftCur = $(this).position().left,
    ulwrapHalfWidth = $('.ulwrap').width() / 2,
    elHalfWidth = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;


  $(this).parent().css({
    left: (ulwrapHalfWidth - leftCur - elHalfWidth)
  });

});

$('.ulwrap ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('.ulwrap ul li').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');

  var leftCur = $(this).position().left,
    ulwrapHalfWidth = $('.ulwrap').width() / 2,
    elHalfWidth = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;


  $(this).parent().animate({
    left: (ulwrapHalfWidth - leftCur - elHalfWidth)
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
.content {
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5%;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.ulwrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
li {
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.current {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="m-racecards">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="ulwrap">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>12</li>
        <li>13</li>
        <li>14</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>16</li>
        <li>17</li>
        <li class="current">18</li>
        <li>19</li>
        <li>20</li>
        <li>21</li>
        <li>22</li>
        <li>23</li>
        <li>and so on....</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awsome answer! This was exactly what I was looking for. You made my day, man. :)

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: Loved the little extra touch with the cursor too.. ;)